# R parallel loop returns incomplete result

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
Df = data.frame(Address = c("ANDRES DUARTE 37, ALAGÓN (ZARAGOZA)", "CASTILLO 5, ALAGÓN (ZARAGOZA)", "PORTILLO 4, ALAGÓN (ZARAGOZA)"),
                Latitude = rep(NA, 3),
                Longitude = rep(NA, 3))
```

I'm trying to fill the values in columns `Latitude` and `Longitude` by geocoding the address in column `Address` using the `caRtociudad` package. The simplest solution I could think of was to do a `for()` loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Df)) {
  
  Loc <- caRtociudad::cartociudad_geocode(Df$Address[i])
  
  Df$Latitude[i] = Loc$lat
  Df$Longitude[i] = Loc$lng

}
```

The problem is that the real `Df` object has over 250000 rows and I wanted to speed up the process by using parallel programing with the `foreach` package. What I tried so far does not work as intended for different reasons.

My first attempt was this:

```
Df$Latitude <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(Df), .combine = c, .packages = "caRtociudad") %dopar% {
  
  Lat = try(cartociudad_geocode(Df$Address[i]))
  
  if(class(Lat)[1] == "try-error"){
    Lat = NA
  } else {
    Lat = Loc$lat
  }
  
  return(Lat)
}

Df$Longitude <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(Df), .combine = c, .packages = "caRtociudad") %dopar% {
  
  Lon = try(cartociudad_geocode(Df$Address[i]))
  
  if(class(Lon)[1] == "try-error"){
    Lon = NA
  } else {
    Lon = Loc$lng
  }
  
  return(Lon)
}
```

This fails because it returns the same coordinates for all values even when the addresses are different.

Then I tried:

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(Df), .combine = "rbind", .packages = "caRtociudad", .export = "Df") %dopar% {
  Loc = cartociudad_geocode(Df$Address[i])
  Df$Latitude[i] <<- Loc$lat
  Df$Longitude[i] <<- Loc$lng
}
```

But this returns: `Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'Df' not found"`. I tried several other iterations but all of them returned similar errors and I don't really know what to try anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us sample Spanish addresses to test the code?

Comment: I edited the question to provide three addresses which all have different coordinates.

Comment: `Lat = Loc$lat` You don't calculate `Loc` in your loop. Should this be `Lat = Lat$lat`?

Comment: Btw., you can't have side effects (like `<<-`) in parallelized code because the workers don't have access to the calling environment of your main session.

Comment: Ok, that was it. I tried so many things that in the end it was the simplest error. That's frustrating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland pointed out in the comments, the problem was in my own code as I misspelled two variables. The following code works as intended:

```
 Df$Latitude <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(Df), .combine = c, .packages = "caRtociudad") %dopar% {
  
  Lat = try(cartociudad_geocode(Df$Address[i]))
  
  if(class(Lat)[1] == "try-error"){
    Lat = NA
  } else {
    Lat = Lat$lat
  }
  
  return(Lat)
}

Df$Longitude <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(Df), .combine = c, .packages = "caRtociudad") %dopar% {
  
  Lon = try(cartociudad_geocode(Df$Address[i]))
  
  if(class(Lon)[1] == "try-error"){
    Lon = NA
  } else {
    Lon = Lon$lng
  }
  
  return(Lon)
}
```